# Where to put business logic in Eclipse RCP program

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing a small application in RCP to wrap around the business logic in another (non-RCP) simulation library. I can access and use the library fine from any of my plugins, but I don't know where I should put the instance of the Simulation library so that, say, one of the command handlers can make calls to it.

From reading the docs it sounds like I should be storing 'global' information like this in the workbench - but I still don't really understand how to do that.

Help?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *the instance of the simulation library*? You can access your library, but want to add what exactly?

Comment: I mean I have an instance of the SimulationFactory or whatever. The class shouldn't matter. I'm asking where to put data that actions can affect and views can find.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, but if you need global access the normal way to get that would be to provide a singleton instance through a static method, e.g. ‘SimulationFactory.getInstance()‘.

Answer (score 2):

First, the business layer (BL) can and should reside in its' own plugin. That will provide decent decoupling between the layers.

Second, you should carefully decide what the interface should be and which classes are exposed. Ideally, you should mostly expose interfaces and data objects.

Finally, decide how the "hand shake" works. E.g., how to obtain the initial interface to the BL. Since it is a Plugin, it could have an Activator which loads it. You could add a method in the activator which returns the BL interface.

If you are looking for something more decoupled, you could create an extension point or deploy the BL as an OSGi service, but that's a bit of an overkill for you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I see two ways:

1. Store the instance in the model plug-in itself, using ‘SimulationFactory.getInstance(String myAppId)‘. The passed String is a constant in you app that is always used, when obtaining the reference.
2. Define a new class e.g. GlobalAccess in you app that is initilized with an instance of your model and has some getter (whether you use a single instance again or only provide public static methods is a matter of taste).

The seocond way is similar to some classes in eclipse like platfom or platformui, where you can obtain initial references and navigate through the workbench.

*edit*

i just found a tutorial that might help you:
[Passing Data between Plug-ins](http://www.techjava.de/topics/2009/07/passing-data-between-plug-ins/)